# mvc 4 responsive for web site and mobile - how to start

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

I need help please with getting started with MVC 4. I was asked to create a responsive index HTML page.

The output  must be responsive and compatible for browser and mobile devices including the graphics.

The website is only graphics with a description of the image - and stores the path of the image and description in SQL Server. So, I need to use CSS to layout the images and connect to SQL to get the description and location of the images.

I need to also use CSS and I see that the project's SCRIPTS folder contains JQuery and Knockout.

I have never used MVC but figured that if they think I can do it then I will take it as a chance to finally learn MVC.

How can I start?

Thanks

Comment: Probably start with opening visual studio. -- In all seriousness, this is going to get down-voted because of the format. If you have a specific question (with an example of what you've already tried) that would be fitting. But, as it stands, this is way too vague.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started I'll try to make the story short:

1. Server side

   - Asp.net mvc (generated dynamic html based on data from DB or other data sources)
   - Learn about Asp.net templates and Razor view engine.
   - Currently the visual studio template for Asp.net MVC project comes with all components required to make a website responsive like bootstrap.js/css, jquery.js etc.
2. Client  side

   - Finally all has to be transformed into the HTML so you must be familiar with HTML 5. As almost all browser supports it.
   - You must know CSS.
   - You must learn using Bootstrap library and it's grid system.
   - Specific to you requirement focus on Images and how bootstrap apply css based on device size.

Target for smallest and largest device to manage your content sizing and adjustments.

Good luck!!

Comment: Thanks. The project came with knockout.
    The layout of the page has to be something like in the image and good for web+ mobile  
    
      [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc9ED.png
    
    Also, I don't understand the solution  sent - app_data folder contains the following-  Gallery.edmx
      Gallery.context.tt
     Gallery.diagram
     Gallery.tt ->images.cs
                     ->media.cs
     Gallery.mdf
    
    From what I read I understand that only the mdf should be in the app_data folder and all the others files under the MODELS folder. 
   What do I put in the models folder?